# How to setup Eloquent Models ManyToMany for self-joins

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, relational-database

I have two tables, `products` and `pack_product`

```
`product` table: product_id, model, price;
```

```
`pack_product` table: product_id, pack_id;
```

```
`product` table data:
product_id  model   price
1   model1  100
2   model2  150
3   model3  200
4   Pack1   300
5   Pack2   400

`pack_product` table data:
product_id  pack_id  
1   4
2   4
3   5
```

I registered all relationships in the Products model class and I would like to fetch all product data from the pivot table, but I getting empty array.

Products model:

```
  /**
   * Products can belong to many packs
  */
  public function packs(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(static::class, 'pack_product', 'products_id', 'pack_id');
  }

  /**
   * Pack can have many products
  */
  public function products(){
      return $this->belongsToMany(static::class, 'pack_product', 'pack_id', 'products_id');
  }
```

Controller

```
$products = new Products;
$products->products()->get();
// or
$product = Products::find(1);
$product->packs;

// getting [] output
```

***UPDATE***

The relations are connected right, but I cannot to print them.

Comment: use model name instead of `static::class` . For example : `Products::class`,

Comment: I tried both ways and still not getting the right output.

Comment: Maybe your model name same as your function. That make problem.

Comment: `$product= Products::find(1)->packs()->get();` Try that